# Reducing multiple blank lines into single blank line. Exceptional case

Tags: regular-expression, ex-mode, global-command

I want to join multiple consecutive blank lines into single blank line.

To do this, I use the following global command:

```
g/^\s*$/,/./-j
```

But this doesn't work in some exceptional cases. For example in the following scenario, 3 blank lines between "c" and "d" are reduced to 2 blank lines instead of 1.

[image: Figure 1]  [image: Figure 2]

In first figure, line 6 has no space. Line 7 has one space. Line 8 has no space.

Why does the above command not work in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Why your command doesn't work

The simple answer is the `.` as the end range for your `:j` command will match the space in your offending line. This means that your nearly empty line will not be removed/compressed.

This can be solved by searching for `\S` (non-whitespace character) instead of `.`

```
:g/^\s*$/,/\S/-j
```

### We can do better

The following command will work with your inconsistent whitespace issues and is much shorter:

```
:v/\S/,//-j
```

The fully expanded command is as follows:

```
:vglobal/\S/ .,/\S/-1join
```

#### Overview

For every blank line, `:join` the current line with the line above the next non-empty line, `\S`.

#### Glory of details

- `:v` is short for `:vglobal`
- `:v/{pat}/{cmd}` will run `{cmd}` on every line *not* matching `{pat}`
- `\S` will match a non-whitespace character
- `:join` (`:j` for short) command will join lines together. For this example you can think of it as compressing a block of blank lines into 1 blank line.
- The `:j` command takes a range. e.g. `.,//-`
- The range is `.,/\S/-1`
- The start range is the current line, `.`. However `.` can be assumed so leave it blank.
- The end of the range is `/\S/-1`. Which means find the next line with a non-whitespace character and then use the line right above it (`-1`)
- Since the pattern is the same pattern used in the `:v` command we can reuse the pattern. `//` is shorthand to reuse the last search pattern.
- `-1` can be shorted to just `-` as the 1 can be assumed
- `.,/\S/-1` becomes `,//-` after we shorten it

For more help see:

```
:h :j
:h :v
:h :g
:h /\S
:h :range
:h /
```

Comment: Cool (+1) -- vim is always surprising.

Answer (score 1):

Using substitution:

```
:%s/\v(\n\s*){2,}/\r\r/
```

- substitute 2 or more newlines `(\n){2,}` with a empty line (`\n\n`)
- `\v` (very magical) was used to simplify the necessity of protections (`\{2,\}`)

Answer (score 0):

Your global command is explained in details [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/1921/4939).

```
g/^\s*$/,/./-j
```

If I understood the post correctly, I think your problem comes from this part:

```
,/./-
```

It defines the range of lines on which the `join` command has to operate.

The range begins with the current line (an empty line which can contain whitespace as described by the pattern `^\s*$`) and ends one line above the next line containing **any** character (including a space).

So I think that in your example, when the global command `g` finds the empty line number 6, the join command `j` looks for a line containing any character (`/./`) and finds a space on line 7, then goes back one line above (`-` ; line 6 again) to determine the final line to collapse. Therefore `j` joins the lines between current line 6 and final line 6, which means it doesn't join anything.

After that it joins line 7 and 8.

If you want the `join` command to ignore the space when searching for the last line to collapse, you could replace `.` (any character) with `\S` (any non whitespace character).

It would give:

```
g/^\s*$/,/\S/-j
```

A more readable version of the same command could be:

```
global/^\s*$/ .,/\S/-1 join
```

The dot `.` in this last command is used in the range `.,/\S/-1` and not in a search pattern, so this time it doesn't stand for any character but for the current line.
And `.,/\S/-1` is a range like `a,b` where `a` = `.` and `b`=`/\S/-1`.

It could be read like this:

*global command (`global`), whenever you find an empty line (`/^\s*$/`) execute the `join` command between the current line (`.`) and one line above (`-1`) the next line containing no whitespace (`/\S/`).*