# How does this search-and-replace command work? `:g /start1/.,/start2/-1 move /end/-1`

Tags: search, replace

I read this description of a different example, [substitute command](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1920/how-does-g-j-reduce-multiple-blank-lines-to-a-single-blank-work-in-vi) and it was very helpful, but I'm still not fully certain how to interpret the commands in `:g /start1/.,/start2/-1 move /end/-1`.  It is supposed to be something that has the text `start1` on some line, followed by text, followed by a line that contains `start2`, followed by a line that has `end`.  In outline, like this:

```
texttexttext 
.Rh start1 
.Rf some text 
some more 
... 
.Rh start2 
more text 
... 
.Rh end 
textytextytext
```

The search-and-replace command is supposed to take everything from `.Rh start1` to just before `.Rh start2` and move it between `.Rh end` and `textytextytext`.

The way I read it so far, `:g /start1/...` says to globally search for `start1` and do `...`.  Now since the `...` is `.,/start2/-1 move /end/-1` what does this mean?  I take the `.` to be a regex for "any character", which is just followed by a comma.  Is Vim searching for that character-comma combination?  Or is it replacing the start1 line with it?

Answer (score 2):

After reading some websites I think I may have answered my own question.  I believe the behavior goes like this:

`:g/start1/...`

indeed means, throughout the document, search for "start1" and do "...".

The "..." is `.,/start2/-1 ...` where the `.` is actually not a regex but a Vim symbol that effectively refers to the line on which the search string was found, and the comma means "select everything from the first part to the next part".  The first part was, as we've seen, the line on which "start1" appears.  The next part is the `start2/-1` which is the next line on which "start2" appears, and then back-stepped by 1.  So this effectively selects everything from start1 to start2, not including the line containing start2.

The command `move` is then given and blah blah blah the rest is obvious.

Comment: "After reading some websites […]" Why don't you read Vim's built-in documentation instead?

Comment: I've read that too, up to a point.  But it is at times not the most readable, so I try to check out many sources.